# How to await import in Remix

Tags: reactjs, pdf, remix

Using Remix 1.16
A simple problem: I need to import a module (pdf.js) conditionally.

Installed it: `npm install pdfjs-dist`

Copied it to /public: `cp ./node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.min.js ./public/`

In a button click event:

```
if (typeof document !== "undefined") {
    const pdfJS = await import('pdfjs-dist/build/pdf');
    console.log(pdfJS.GlobalWorkerOptions) // undefined
```

Am I missing something?
Are there any examples of how to conditionally import a module in Remix?

Comment: Most likely you import pdf.js instead of pdf.worker. Fix your import like this "import('pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker')" or "import('pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.min.js')"

Answer (score 0):

Is was lacking `.then(...)`:

```
const pdfJS = await import('pdfjs-dist/build/pdf').then(module=>module?.default);
```

BTW, even without copying the min dist to public, I could load it:

```
const pdfJS = await import('pdfjs-dist').then(module=>module?.default);
```